# Drop rows of data based on a fields length

Tags: sas

I'm having some issues with data quality and the subsequent formatting of the data.

The data is DOB in this format 20111021, but some entries are one of the following - '0''101''10101'.

Can I drop rows of data in a data step where the DOB is like this, or if the DOB is not 8 numbers long? If so, how?

Answer (score 7):

```
data clean ;
  set dirty ;
  if input(DOB,??yymmdd8.) then output ;
run ;
```

Basically, attempt to convert DOB into a SAS date based on yymmdd8. format. If successful, output the row. The ?? suppresses errors in the log for the rows which fail conversion.

Comment: Didn't know about "??". Cool.

Comment: Right back to basics - I was making it more complicated than i needed to.

Comment: Thanks. I didnt specify earlier, but it was having issues with this, a format error was coming up stating the length was too short for date. Anyway, I resolved it with just a If DELETE statement. I was making it more complicated than needed! Cheers

Comment: A single ? will also work but will display messages to the log as well.

Comment: Indeed - interesting stuff! [Here's the language manual reference](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000146292.htm) for those who are curious.  Look under "How Invalid Data is Handled".

Comment: Oops - I was wrong.  The single ? will suppress the warning but still set \_ERROR\_ to 1.